# Unable to create spark cluster with data lake store

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

When I am trying to create Spark cluster I'm getting below error.

DeploymentDocument 'AmbariConfiguration_1_7' failed the validation. Error: 'Service Principal Details are invalid'

Can someone help me here please.

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this issue in Template Deployment? Did you give Base64 coded value in your clusteridentity's certificate ?